# Vimeo progress request returns "options.uri is a required argument"

Tags: vimeo-api, node-request

Having issues completing a PUT upload using Vimeo's API. An upload progress call returns: "Error: options.uri is a required argument."

Mind you, everything does seem to upload properly; I am just very leery of success in the presence of errors.

Relevant code (Node.js) follows:

```
app.post('/api/vimeo/complete', function(req, res) {
request({
    method: 'PUT',
    json: true,
    url: req.body.upload_link_secure,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer OBSCURO-PATRONUM',
        'Content-Range': '*/*'
    }
}, function(error, response, body){
    //console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
    console.log('progress error: ' + error);
    fs.writeFile('server_logs/vimeo-progress-log.json', JSON.stringify(response), function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('log writing error: ' + err);
        } else {
            console.log('Vimeo progress log written.');
        }
    });
    res.json(body);
});
request({
    method: 'DELETE',
    json: true,
    url: 'https://api.vimeo.com' + req.body.uri,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer OBSCURO-PATRONUM'
    }
}, function(error, response, body){
    console.log('complete error: ' + error);
    console.log('complete body: ' + body);
    res.json(body);
});
});
```

Comment: Is the error thrown from one of the lines of code you have provided, or deeper? Also where is the request method coming from?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply. Been working my tail off on the actual recording architecture. The errors are thrown in the response object returned from the request to complete the upload (method: DELETE). Request is a convenience Node.js module: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). The flow of control is: client records -> client requests upload ticket -> server returns upload ticket to client -> client uploads to vimeo -> client sends completion request to server

Answer (score 1):

Try using uri instead of url in the object passed to the request method. The docs claim both work (https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) but you might be using a different version of the library.

This definitely sounds like a request error, not a vimeo error.

Comment: It should work with both uri and url. Make sure webhook is the full url with http:// or https://.